Derivative of the inverse of a polynomial
I have a function
$$f(x)=x^3+n^{-a}\left(x^2+2\sqrt{3}x\right)\qquad n\in \mathbb N,\quad 0<a<1\quad x\in \mathbb R$$
I have verified this is invertible.
Define $$g(x)=f^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right).$$
I am trying to compute the asymptotic of
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x)|_{\frac{1}{n}}$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
I have tried to use inverse function theorem, but I don't have good information about $g(x)$, so I am stuck.
Do anyone has an idea how to proceed?
